# Prove $f$ is positive and has no roots

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, exponential-function

I need help to prove the following function is positive for all $0<x<1$, $0<y<1$, $x\neq y$ and an integer $a\ge 2$,

$$f(x,y,a)=(y-1) x^a \left((a-2) x^2-(a-1) x (y+1)+a y\right)+(x-1)^2 x y^a.$$

According to all numerical testing of $f$ this claim is definitely true, but how can I formally prove it?

Comment: Are you sure you typed that in right? I get a value of $f(v, u, a) = -0.04384$ for $v = 0.1$, $u =0.2$ and $a = 2$ (and numerous others).

Comment: Thank you for the observation @Infiaria I didn't type it right. Sorry for that.

Comment: The function was fixed.